# Too many redirects using .htaccess file to cut and change URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've go a .htaccess file on my server with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)? index.php?i=$1 [L]
```

When I run this I've got something like this:

```
http://example.com/index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.phpi=index.php?i=XYZ
```

How to get link look like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?i=XYZ
```

from link look like this

```
http://example.oom/XYZ/ABC/123
```

I only need first XYZ to `index.php?i=XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ index.php?i=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```